# [File IO Error in porting from python2 to python 3]

Tags: python

I port my project from python 2.7 to python 3.6

What I was doing in python 2.7

1)Decode from Base 64

2)Uncompress using Gzip

3)Read line by line and add in file

```
    bytes_array = base64.b64decode(encryptedData)
    fio = StringIO.StringIO(bytes_array)
    f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=fio)
    decoded_data = f.read()
    f.close()
    f = file("DecodedData.log",'w')
    for item in decoded_data:
        f.write(item)
    f.close()
```

I tried the same thing using python 3 changes but It is not working giving one error or the other.

I am not able to use StringIO giving error

```
#initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

So I try this

```
    bytes_array = base64.b64decode(encryptedData)

    #initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

    fio = io.BytesIO(bytes_array)
    f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=fio)
    decoded_data =f.read()
    f= open("DecodedData.log",'w')
    for item in decoded_data:

        f.write(item)
    f.close()
```

This gives error in the line f.write(item) that

```
    write() argument must be str, not int
```

To my surprsie,item actually contains an integer when i print it.(83,83,61,62)

I think it as I have not given the limit,it is reading as many as it can.
So I try to read file line by line

```
   f= open("DecodedData.log",'w')
   with open(decoded_data) as l:
    for line in l:    
        f.write(line)
```

But it still not working and \n also printing in file.
Can some suggest what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
decoded_data = f.read()
```

Will result in decoded_data being a `bytes` object. `bytes` objects are iterable, when you iterate them they will return each byte value from the data as an integer (0-255). That means when you do

```
for item in decoded_data:
    f.write(item)
```

then `item` will be each integer byte value from your raw data.

```
f.write(decoded_data)
```

You've opened `f` in text mode, so you'll need to open it in binary mode if you want to write raw binary data into it. But the fact you've called the file `DecodedData.log` suggests you want it to be a (human readable?) text file.

So I think overall this will be more readable:

```
gzipped_data = base64.b64decode(encryptedData)
data = gzip.decompress(gzipped_data)  
with open("DecodedData.log",'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

There's no need for the intermediate BytesIO at all, gzip has a decompress method (https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.decompress)

Comment: thanks @Tom Dalton : Will check tomorrow and will select as the accepted answer :) after checking

Comment: method was gzip.decompress :)